# "File to import not found or unreadable: materialize": Materialize CSS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm trying to use the Materialize CSS framework in my rails project, but I'm running into the following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: materialize. Load paths: 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/photoid/app/assets/images 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/photoid/app/assets/javascripts 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/photoid/app/assets/stylesheets 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/photoid/vendor/assets/javascripts 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/photoid/vendor/assets/stylesheets 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/assets/stylesheets 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/vendor/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.6.3.1/app/assets/fonts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.6.3.1/app/assets/stylesheets 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cloudinary-1.2.0/vendor/assets/html 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cloudinary-1.2.0/vendor/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/stylesheets 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/javascripts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/fonts 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/images 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/stylesheets
```

**application.scss**

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*= require font-awesome
*/

// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"

@import "materialize";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.infinitescroll
```

I do have the [Materialize gem](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass) installed. Am I getting the error because I already have bootstrap installed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should restart your server after adding a gem.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly congruous to the original problem, the original question came up high on my google efforts to solve my problem.  I think this is a good place to drop a small hint for anyone else who encounters it.

In my case, the issue was that the default CSS file for rails was named 'application.*css*', not 'application.*scss*'.

Answer (score 1):

if you see this in 2021. Your problem may be the same as mine, and maybe it's the only question about it on Stack overflow.

So, I was running an old open-source project. got the same problem and the reason where that ***materialize-sass*** got an update and not working the same way as when the project made. for the time I'm writing this. there is only 2 version. back then there where only one so the Gemfile had this line `gem 'materialize-sass'` when I installed the project there where a new version that downloaded since no specific version in the Gemfile. the solution was just changing that line to the specific old version `gem 'materialize-sass', '~> 0.100.2'`

if you faced the same issue in the future try to check a different versions. you can find the versions on the main website for  [materialize](https://materializecss.com/)